# Mono System.InvalidProgramException Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue:.ctor (string): method body is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ubuntu, mono

I am trying to run MVC4 web application on Ubuntu 12.10.
I installed mono and I can run a very very simple mvc project. But whenever i try to run my own application I always get this error :

System.InvalidProgramException Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue:.ctor (string): method body is empty.

When I type mono -V ; the output is below :

> Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.3 ((no/d6946b4 Tue Aug  4 04:52:25 PDT
>   2015)

The version information that seen on the browser is :

> Version Information: 4.0.3 ((no/d6946b4 Tue Aug 4 04:52:25 PDT 2015);
>   ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020

Comment: how did you install mono?

Comment: It seems that you built your own Mono from source. You should install from Xamarin feed and make sure in your bin folder there is no dlls that are conflicted with Mono's dlls in GAC.

Comment: @knocte i build mono from  source code

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your reply. i tried what you said but still same error.

Comment: how did you build it? did you make sure that you had no mono packages installed before installing from sources?

Comment: @knocte yes i am pretty sure there is no mono packages installed before. I cant understand the question how am i build it

Comment: well, how did you build it? what prefix did you use at configure time?

Comment: and what prefix did you use when configuring xsp?

Comment: the prefix is /usr/local

Comment: did you also install xsp? did you use the same prefix?

Comment: yes i installed the xsp4 and used the same prefix

Answer (score 2):

I got this error in Xamarin Cross Platform program.
It ran good in android simulator and crash in iOS simulator
I added System.net and System.Net.Http again in iOS Section in Solution explorer and it worked well

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error yesterday.
I think the problem is my two projects, I have two different versions of Modernhttpclient dlls.

All I did is removing system.Net dll , ModernHttpclient, OkHttp Dll and then re-added the latest version of these dlls.
Also I have added Modernhttpclient dll via nuget. That fixed the problem for me.